# How to open a URL in default browser using WinINet API in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, url, networking, wininet

I am working on a C++ authentication code which needs to open a URL on browser for entering an OTP, the problem is I don't know Windows Programming since I am a rookie, I am looking for some code specifically using WinINet library to open a URL in default browser, is there any links or codes that could help me?

Answer (score 2):

You want [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew)

```
#include <windows.h>`
#include <shellapi.h>
```

Then to invoke:

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"https://www.stackoverflow.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);  // unicode
```

OR

```
ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", "https://www.stackoverflow.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);   // ansi
```